# SeleniumException: ERROR: Unknown command

Tags: selenium, user-extensions.js

I'm using setExtensionJs with an user-extensions.js file that defines a doFoo prototype.
This throws an exception everytime Selenium starts:

```
CHECKPOINT-FAIL com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Unknown command "doFoo"
```

The setExtensionJs call is of course before of the start call.

Launching Selenium with:

```
-userExtensions user-extensions.js
```

works without problem.

Does anyone has an idea why I got the exception?

Comment: The solution from http://stuvel.eu/archive/131/extending-selenium-from-the-client-driver doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted over at [the gyrmination blog](http://ttwhy.org/home/blog/2008/05/14/selenium-rc-per-session-extension-javascript/):

> Just a heads-up for anyone trying to
>   use this SetExtensionJS() interface.
>   You can’t use this to create a
>   Selenium command like you can with
>   user-extensions.js, because the code
>   that registers command handlers is run
>   before SetExtensionJS() injects your
>   code.

Sorry :-(